# I am getting an undefined error in my JS, but not sure why

Tags: javascript

I am getting `undefined` in my console.log(), at `console.log(item.ResponseId);`  This in turn is causing my $ajax.done() function to fail because the value needs to be the returned value of the initial call.  Also, `console.log(msg.ResponseId);` is outputting an integer as expected.

```
var rdetail = new Array();
        $('.choiceinput').each(function (i, obj) {
            rdetail.push({
                "ResponseId": 0,
                "ResponseDetailVal": $(this).val(),
                "QuestioChoicesId": $(this).attr('id')
            });
        })


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Forecaster/userResponse/",
            data: data
        }).done(function (msg) {
            console.log(msg.ResponseId);
            for (var item in rdetail) {
                item.ResponseId = msg.ResponseId;
                console.log(item.ResponseId);
            }
            console.log("Last: ");
            console.log(rdetail);
            $.post('/Forecaster/userResponseDetails/',
                     JSON.stringify(rdetail),
                null, 'application/json');
        })
```

Comment: @adeneo: `item` is a string, `rdetail` is an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `for( item in rdetail)`, the *keys* of `rdetail` are assigned to `item` one by one. Since a key is a string, assigning a property to it does nothing*.

Did you maybe mean `rdetail[item].ResponseId`?

<sub>* It actually wraps the primitive string in a `String()` object, assigns the property to it, then discards it</sub>

Comment: Shouldn't you also not `for..in` over an array?

Comment: @RocketHazmat True, but that's a comment at best, not part of answering the question itself :)

Comment: Well, describing the proper way to iterate over an array would be *helpful*.